# Unable to debug in the processElememt part of the DoFn in Intellij IDE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I am writing to run a test case locally, while doing so. thr code never halts at the breakpoints set into the @processElement . I tried Alt+shift+F7 but failed to break inside the code.

Comment: Could you share your test code, are you sure the test is blocking wait until the pipeline is finished?

Comment: can you share your test code?